# Javascript Validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am wanting to make validation to my Email form. Unfortunately I cannot get this piece of code to work. When I am clicking submit without entering any data in to the form it will send.

I am wanting it not to send without the right Characters in the Email

I have attached a screenshot below of my code

[image]

Comment: Could you insert your code as text in your post, instead of as an image?

Comment: so you had time to do a screenshot and upload to imgur, but didn't paste actual code which take LESS time to do. Post your real code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Add code and efforts to your question

Comment: When I am adding the code it doesn't set out in the right way. This is why I placed an Image.

Comment: what is it? {1,} only one??

Comment: dont worry about the right way, we will update it.. :p

Comment: You are missing a bracket for sure. Change to `onsubmit="return validate(this)"` and your function to `function validate(theForm) { var reg...; var address = theForm.emailAddress.value; ...... if (...) { alert(....); theForm.emailAddress.focus(); return false; } return true; }` - and never call anything `name="submit"` - lastly read how to format here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Possibile duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regex as:

```
var email_regex = /^[\w%_\-.\d]+@[\w.\-]+.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/; // reg ex email check

if(emailAddress == "") 
{
    // error if empty
} 
else 
{
    if(!email_regex.test(emailAddress))
    { 
        // invalid error
    }   
    else
    {
        // success
    }
}
```